# Installing octave dependency: tbb failed

Tags: opencv, homebrew

Found this on a gist, thought it useful to post here:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/18111

while installing opencv

```
==> Installing octave dependency: tbb
==> Downloading 
http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/sites/default/files/software_releases/source/

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Download failed:
http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/sites/default/files/software_releases/source/tbb41_20121003oss_src.tgz
```

Answer (score 5):

```
brew update
```

to get the corrected tbb URL.